# Why does one Bayes evaluation function work and the other not? it the same thing in my point and i must know why

Tags: python, file, machine-learning

I don't understand why the first example doesn't work and the second does. They are the same code and for it's good to know why it didn't work thnks for the help.

```
def naive_bayes_eval(test_sms_file, f):
    Precision=1
    est_spam =0
    pas_spam =0
    nbr_spam =0

    for ligne in open(test_sms_file, 'r').readlines():
        if("spam" in ligne):
            nbr_spam = nbr_spam + 1
            if f(ligne.replace('spam',''))== 1:
                est_spam=est_spam+1
        if("ham" in ligne):
            if( f(ligne.replace('ham',''))== 1):
                pas_spam = pas_spam+1
    recall = est_spam/nbr_spam;         
    if (est_spam + pas_spam)>0:
        Precision = est_spam/(est_spam + pas_spam)
    return(recall,Precision)
```

```
def naive_bayes_eval(test_sms_file, f):
    Precision=1
    est_spam =0
    pas_spam =0
    nbr_spam =0
    f=open(test_sms_file, 'r')
    lines=f.readlines()
    for ligne in lines:
        if("spam" in ligne):
            nbr_spam = nbr_spam + 1
            if f(ligne.replace('spam',''))== 1:
                est_spam=est_spam+1
        if("ham" in ligne):
            if( f(ligne.replace('ham',''))== 1):
                pas_spam = pas_spam+1
    recall = est_spam/nbr_spam;         
    if (est_spam + pas_spam)>0:
        Precision = est_spam/(est_spam + pas_spam)
    return(recall,Precision)
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "don't work", is there errors, exceptions, ...

Comment: It should be the other way around - 2nd should break because you overwrite `f` with the file, thus breaking `f(ligne.replace('spam',''))`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the first does work while the second doesn't?

```
def naive_bayes_eval(test_sms_file, f):
    ...
    f=open(test_sms_file, 'r')
```

This line overwrites the `f` parameter.